# When trying to run the code below in scilab, i get an error on line 6 "inconsistent row/column dimensions"

Tags: scilab

Here is the code, Line 6 is where I'm getting the 'inconsistent row/column dimensions' error

```
T=10:10:500;
k=1.38e-23;
Eg=1.1*1.6e-19;
Nc=5.41e15*(T.^1.5);
Nv=2.23e15*(T.^1.5);
ni=sqrt(Nc*Nv')*exp(-((Eg)/(2*k*T)));
plot2d(T', ni)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your operands are vectors you are missing a dot before each element-wise operator (the multiplication before the exponential and the division):

```
ni=sqrt(Nc*Nv').*exp(-((Eg)./(2*k*T)));
```